# How can we measure the tilt of steering wheel in car without any special sensor for it?

Tags: electrical

I am searching for some possible way so that I can get the tilt or amount by which the steering wheel is rotated and without any use of special sensor for it , in Indian Cars like Swift D-Zire ,  Beat or ZEN

Comment: Carry a protractor with you?

Comment: Are you asking if you can access a tilt sensor on the steering wheel by accessing something from the engine computer?  Or are you wondering if there's an easy way to see that it's tilted?

Comment: I am asking if i can  access a tilt sensor on the steering wheel by accessing something from the engine computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If there is no steering angle sensor to input that information to the vehicles computer, you can't extract that information. Can I ask what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: by measuring the angle i want to get the tilt of steering on a straight road , so that i can get the idea of wheel alignment ..!

Comment: The steering wheel can be off centre without the alignment necessarily being out. Take it to a tyre fitter, they'll sort it out

Comment: Sir i am interested in measuring it , not correcting it at i have to use its data for some other purpose.